# Merge two dictionaries based on the same keys

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have the following:

```
dict1 Dictionary<int, string>
1, "A"
2, "B"
3, "C"


dict2 Dictionary<int, string>
1, "G"
2, "H"
3, "I"
```

I want two create a third dictionary where the key and value are the values of the above where the keys match:

```
dict3 Dictionary<strin, string>
"A", "G"
"B", "H"
"C", "I"
```

I can accomplish this with two loops very easily, but what would be the lambda equivalent?

Comment: what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Join` them and use `ToDictionary`

```
dict1.Join(dict2, kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Key, 
              (kv1, kv2) => new {Val1 = kv1.Value, Val2 = kv2.Value})
            .ToDictionary(arg => arg.Val1, arg => arg.Val2);
```

Comment: I prefer this method because it is more obvious!

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => dict2[x.Key]);
```

This assumes `dict1` does not contain any duplicate values and `dict2` has all the keys `dict1` has.

Comment: KeyNotFound exception if some key is missing

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable.Join` to make sure that you are selecting entries which both exist in first and second dictionaries:

```
dict1.Join(dict2, 
           d1 => d1.Key, 
           d2 => d2.Key, 
           (d1, d2) => new { Key = d1.Value, Value = d2.Value })
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
```